# Laptop screen grey, works with external monitor

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lcd, sony-vaio

Two years ago the screen on my Sony Vaio SVS13A190S suddenly stopped working correctly. It displays only grey vertical lines. However, it works perfectly fine with an external monitor. I don't know what caused the issue.

The pattern of grey lines imitates what *should* be displayed on the screen. For instance, if I open a window in some area of my screen, the grey lines change in that area. Adjusting the screen brightness makes the grey brighter or darker accordingly.

I opened up the screen and I don't see anything overtly wrong (e.g. a broken cable or connection).

Grey Screen:
[image]

Bezel Removed:
[image]

Connection:
[image]

How can I determine what's causing this problem, and, in particular, whether replacing the screen will resolve it? I've found replacement screens for sale, but I won't buy one unless I'm confident it will fix the problem.

Edit: I ended up buying a replacement screen (from a place with a good return policy, in case it didn't work). I replaced the screen yesterday and it runs perfectly now.